# AWS Connect - Playing a mix of bargeable and un-bargeable prompts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I'm creating a Connect Contact flow. In one of my Lambdas, a map of prompts as strings is created which is then combined together as a single string and then assigned as a contact attribute in the flow. Then this prompt attribute is passed to a Play Prompt block to play back to the caller.

But lets say within this map of prompts, one of them is un-bargeable, meaning I don't want the caller to be able to interrupt through that particular prompt. Does anyone know the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The Play Prompt block is by definition uninterruptable. It will just play the given prompt until it is complete.

If you want a prompt that the customer can interrupt say by pressing a number, you need to use the Get Customer Input or Store Customer Input blocks.

If you wanted some prompts interruptible and some not you'd have to split the prompts you send back either to multiple key/value pairs or in json that you can access in multiple prompt and get/store blocks.